# finding out percentages in bins for a group by using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, categories

This is a small sanpshot of my dataframe

```
city    trips_in_first_30_days  bins
0   King's Landing  4   (3, 125]
1   Astapor 0   NaN
2   Astapor 3   (2, 3]
3   King's Landing  9   (3, 125]
4   Winterfell  14  (3, 125]
5   Winterfell  2   (1, 2]
6   Astapor 1   (0, 1]
7   Winterfell  2   (1, 2]
8   Winterfell  2   (1, 2]
9   Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
10  Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
11  Winterfell  3   (2, 3]
12  Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
13  King's Landing  0   NaN
14  Astapor 1   (0, 1]
15  Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
16  King's Landing  1   (0, 1]
17  King's Landing  0   NaN
18  King's Landing  6   (3, 125]
19  King's Landing  0   NaN
20  Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
21  Astapor 1   (0, 1]
22  Winterfell  0   NaN
23  King's Landing  0   NaN
24  Astapor 4   (3, 125]
25  Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
26  Astapor 1   (0, 1]
27  Winterfell  3   (2, 3]
28  Winterfell  0   NaN
29  Astapor 1   (0, 1]
... ... ... ...
49970   Winterfell  2   (1, 2]
49971   King's Landing  0   NaN
49972   Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
49973   Astapor 2   (1, 2]
49974   Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
49975   Winterfell  11  (3, 125]
49976   King's Landing  0   NaN
49977   Astapor 4   (3, 125]
49978   Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
49979   Winterfell  0   NaN
49980   Astapor 1   (0, 1]
49981   Astapor 0   NaN
49982   King's Landing  0   NaN
49983   Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
49984   Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
49985   Astapor 1   (0, 1]
49986   Winterfell  0   NaN
49987   Winterfell  3   (2, 3]
49988   King's Landing  1   (0, 1]
49989   Winterfell  1   (0, 1]
49990   Astapor 1   (0, 1]
49991   Winterfell  0   NaN
49992   King's Landing  1   (0, 1]
49993   Astapor 3   (2, 3]
49994   Astapor 1   (0, 1]
49995   King's Landing  0   NaN
49996   Astapor 1   (0, 1]
49997   Winterfell  0   NaN
49998   Astapor 2   (1, 2]
49999   Astapor 0   NaN
```

`df['bins']` is a categorical that I have introduced by using `pd.cut` to put `trips_in_first_30_days` in different **bins**.

Now I am interested in finding out when **grouped by city** what percentage of `trips_in_first_30_days` fall in  various bins?

For instance , for city **astapor** how many percent  `trips_in_first_30_days` fall in (0,1]; how many in (1,2] and so on?

Is it possible to do that at all as **bins** are **dtype category** and cannot have operations performed on? And how to accomplish this?

**EDIT**:

On trying out the suggested solution:

```
def calc_bin_percentage(group_df):
bins_count = group_df.groupby("bins")["trips_in_first_30_days"].count()
return 100 * bins_count / len(group_df)
new_df.groupby("city").apply(calc_bin_percentage)
```

The out put is as follows:

```
bins    (0, 1]  (1, 2]  (2, 3]  (3, 125]
city                
Astapor 31.105601   14.787710   6.973509    14.878432 
King's Landing  22.408687   14.471866   7.541955    20.710760
Winterfell  28.689578   14.959719   8.017655    20.371957
```

The sum of the percentages of the each of the cities should be **100** but that is not the case

Comment: Can you show us what you expect the result to look like?

Comment: Hi, please check now.

Answer (score 2):

For this, it is useful to remember that functions used in `apply` of `groupby` could return a `pd.Series` object (this is called [flexible apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) in Pandas documentation).

Try the following code:

```
def calc_bin_percentage(group_df):
    bins_count = group_df.groupby("bins")["trips_in_first_30_days"].sum()
    return 100 * bins_count / group_df.sum()

df.groupby("city").apply(calc_bin_percentage).unstack().fillna(0)
```

It does the job in two steps - first splits the data by city, and then for every city, calculates the percentage for every bin.

The result should be table with cities as row, and bins as columns.

Comment: Hi, for some reason , in my data when I try this, The sum of the percentages for each group does not equate to 100.

Comment: Could be because of integer division. I guess you are using Python 2 (are all the resulting values integers?). Try multiplying by `100.0` instead of `100` (will force float division). (In Python 3 float division is the default)

Comment: using python 3 and resulting values are floats.

Comment: oh yeah. My bad. Replace `group_df.groupby("bins").count()` with `group_df.groupby("bins")["trips_in_first_30_days"].count()`. What happened was that it counted separately for each column, and put the bins in multiindex (along with the cities). I'll edit the answer to reflect it

Comment: so, now the hierarchial index is gone, but even now the sum is not 100. Same percent values as before

Comment: You have NA for some bins in your data. Currently the code count the percent of **rows** in a certain bin (so, it counts the `NA` in the total). To fix it, use `sum` instead of count. (Editing again. Sorry about the confusion.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141607/discussion-between-tmrlvi-and-optimus-prime).